# vb.net dragdrop with tab control and MDI container

Tags: vb.net, drag-and-drop

I have an MDI container window and a secondary windows housing a simple tab control. I have set the properties accordingly to have the tab drag and drop to the MDI container window.

DragDrop handler finally fires however the "sender" object is not what I was expecting when I did:

debug.print(sender.toString)

I was expecting the source object, the tab control reference but instead it looks like "sender" is the MDI main application window. How do I override this or what setting am I missing?

I should note this is my initializing code:

```
Private Sub tabContainer_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles tabContainer.MouseDown
    tabContainer.DoDragDrop(CType(sender, TabControl), DragDropEffects.Move)
End Sub
```

This leads me to believe that when DragDrop is caught in the MDI container window that "sender" would in deed be the TabControl???

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the sender of the event will always be the control that received the DragDrop notification.  So that's your MDI container since that's where you let go of the button.

There is no mechanism in D+D to identify the source of the dragged object.  Very much by design, it can come from an entirely different process that's completely out of reach.  If you need any additional info beyond what's in the object that's being dragged then you'll need to add that to the object.  Not at all an issue as long as the D+D is inside one app, you can create a little helper class to store whatever you need.